# Get/Hide Nth element in class

Tags: javascript, css

How would I hide the Nth element (lets say the 6th) element that has a class, if that is all I know and I cannot give it a unique id?

Also, how would you hide all elements besides the first 5?

Obviously I can use `display: none;` to hide the element with CSS, but what javascript would I use to do the logic part of this?

Comment: what do you mean "in an class"? the 6th element that has such a class? or the 6th element in an element that has such a class?

Comment: Great clarification. I meant the 6th that has the class. Ill clarify above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` , `.item()` , `for` loop

> How would I hide the Nth element (lets say the 6th) element that has a class

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".abc");

var n = 5;

elems.item(n).style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div class="abc">0</div>
<div class="abc">1</div>
<div class="abc">2</div>
<div class="abc">3</div>
<div class="abc">4</div>
<div class="abc">5</div>
<div class="abc">6</div>
<div class="abc">7</div>
<div class="abc">8</div>
<div class="abc">9</div>
```

---

> Also, how would you hide all elements besides the first 5?

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".abc");

var n = 5;

for (var i = n; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">0</div>
<div class="abc">1</div>
<div class="abc">2</div>
<div class="abc">3</div>
<div class="abc">4</div>
<div class="abc">5</div>
<div class="abc">6</div>
<div class="abc">7</div>
<div class="abc">8</div>
<div class="abc">9</div>
```

Comment: no jquery tag, no jquery in question... why is there jquery in answer?

Comment: In your second fragment, you just need `for (var i = n...`, with no `if` required.

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are siblings (as @charlietfl points out in comments), you could get away doing this in CSS by using:

```
.certain-class:nth-of-type(n+6)
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: assumes they are siblings though

Comment: @Jeremy Use `:nth-of-type()`

Comment: @guest271314 there:)

Comment: Question was for *any element* so `nth-of-type` would not work here.

Comment: This addresses the element with class `.certain-class` which is also the 6th or greater child, **not** the 6th or greater child which has the class `.certain-class`.

Comment: @torazaburo I've specified they had to be siblings